# What is the difference between "can possibly" and "could possibly"

Tags: grammar

"what could possibly go wrong?" and "what can possibly go wrong?"

I am confused because both uses possibly ... what is the difference between the two sentence?

thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

"What could go wrong?" is more of a hypothetical question about the future.

It can be used rhetorically to support an idea by pointing out that it is low-risk.

It's also sometimes used sarcastically to make fun of an obviously bad idea, e.g. "Closing your eyes while driving - what could go wrong?"

---

"What can go wrong?" is less hypothetical and more immediate. I don't hear this phrase nearly as often as the other version. However, it might be used for something like troubleshooting some hardware.

---

In either case, "possibly" is added for emphasis and doesn't change the meaning much.